# Linq query Join shows Error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Linq query Join shows Error

While using `Join in Linq query`,I am getting this Error.

This is the Error which i got.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<xxx.Models.jobxml>' '.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my code

```
var job = from jx in bc.db.jobxml 
      join jad in bc.db.Job_Agent_Details on jx.agent_id equals jad.Id 
      orderby jx.id 
      select new 
      { 
        jx.jobtitle, 
        jx.jobrole, 
        jx.jobhour, 
        jx.companyname, 
        jx.jobposition, 
        jx.location, 
        jx.closedate, 
        jx.jobdescription 
      };
```

Comment: As per your previous question that you deleted, can you show the context this is in? This code itself should not generate an error.

Comment: Please include the compile-time types of `bc.db.jobxml` and `bc.db.Job_Agent_Details`. If those types are `IQueryable` rather than `IQueryable<Foo>` for some `Foo`, that would cause problems...

Comment: Additionally your previous question had a different error message and implied that the types were `IQueryable<anonymous type>` to `IQueryable<jobxml>`

Comment: @Kritner: Sorry , I had some mistakes in the question,So i deleted it.

Comment: You can edit questions, you don't have to delete :P  At this point I can't even reference my previous answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not showing us the context in which this code sits, I am going to guess that the `job` variable is being used elsewhere (as a return variable?) by something expecting `IQueryable<jobxml>`

In the `select` you are creating an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type but you can change this to `jobxml` like this:

```
var job = from jx in bc.db.jobxml 
          join jad in bc.db.Job_Agent_Details on jx.agent_id equals jad.Id 
          orderby jx.id 
          select new jobxml //<-- This is the important change
          { 
              //snip
          };
```

Comment: The only thing you have added is the error message, not the code around this linq query.

Comment: I cant able to take the content from two tables, But By giving jobxml I gave jx,Its working now. Upvoted :)

Comment: Cool. I accepted yours, Kritner also explained the answer nice,Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

To (hopefully) elaborate on DavidG's answer.  The function that your `var job = ...` sits in likely has a method signature such as:

```
public IQueryable<xxx.Models.jobxml> DoStuff()
{

    // some code is here potentially

    var job = from jx in bc.db.jobxml 
      join jad in bc.db.Job_Agent_Details on jx.agent_id equals jad.Id 
      orderby jx.id 
      select new 
      { 
        jx.jobtitle, 
        jx.jobrole, 
        jx.jobhour, 
        jx.companyname, 
        jx.jobposition, 
        jx.location, 
        jx.closedate, 
        jx.jobdescription 
      };

    return job;

}
```

The problem here is your linq query builds an anonymous type object, whereas the function is attempting to return a `IQueryable<xxx.Models.jobxml>`

As DavidG pointed out, your linq query needs to create a type of jobxml, not an anonymous type.  That can be accomplished as such:

```
public IQueryable<xxx.Models.jobxml> DoStuff()
{

    // some code is here potentially

    var job = from jx in bc.db.jobxml 
      join jad in bc.db.Job_Agent_Details on jx.agent_id equals jad.Id 
      orderby jx.id 
      select new xxx.Models.jobxml()
      { 
        JobTitle = jx.jobtitle, 
        JobRole = jx.jobrole, 
        JobHour = jx.jobhour, 
        // the rest of your object properties - note i'm making assumptions about your jobxml object here
      };

    return job;

}
```

Comment: You probably meant to use a different return type for the function right? :)

Comment: Indeed.  List or some other type of ienumerable is what i meant, thanks :)

Comment: The error message suggests `IQueryable` of course :)

Comment: ah... just noticed the updated error message.  I was trying to remember from the last version of the question that was deleted.  Guess I remembered wrong.